# How to Map Array of Images in React Redux application?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

We are currently building an e-commerce website for our clients. But get stuck on the mapping of array images data from API server.

This is a product large Image component:

**ImageZoom Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ImageZoom extends Component {
  render() {
    const { image } = this.props;

    return <img src={`${image}`} className="img-fluid image_zoom_cls-0" />;
  }
}
```

JSON data from rest API.
**JSON Data:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "http://babylandworld.com:8000/apps/product/1/",
        "active": true,
        "slug": "kid-car",
        "sku": "kid-2020",
        "name": "Car",
        "price": 200.0,
        "discount_percent": null,
        "price_unit": "Nepalese Rupee",
        "short_description": "Kids-car for children and kids",
        "description": "SKU generator helps to keep item naming consistent, clear, and easy to remember, even if you have long list of items in your inventory",
        "for_sale": false,
        "for_sale_percent": 0.0,
        "for_sale_price": 150.0,
        "creation_date": "2020-04-30T17:05:41.565249Z",
        "deliverable": true,
        "stock_amount": 14.0,
        "stock_unit": "piece",
        "weight": 20.0,
        "weight_unit": "kilogram",
        "height": null,
        "height_unit": "",
        "length": null,
        "length_unit": "",
        "width": null,
        "width_unit": "",
        "tax_type": "http://babylandworld.com:8000/apps/tax/1/",
        "manufacturer": "Tesla",
        "active_sku": true,
        "active_short_description": true,
        "active_description": true,
        "active_effective_price": true,
        "active_dimension": true,
        "active_weight": true,
        "specification": {
            "type": "2020 model",
            "color": "red"
        },
        "primary_category": "http://babylandworld.com:8000/apps/category/2/",
        "images": [
            {
                "product": 1,
                "name": "kids car",
                "image_file": "http://babylandworld.com:8000/media/products/nmark_logo.png"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is a product image in small size and used in sliding the product images.
**Small Image:**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Slider from "react-slick";

    class SmallImages extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          nav2: null,
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          nav2: this.slider2,
        });
      }

      render() {
        const { items, settings } = this.state;

        var productsnav = settings;
        console.log(items.images.image_file);

        return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 p-0">
              <Slider
                {...productsnav}
                asNavFor={this.props.navOne}
                ref={(slider) => (this.slider2 = slider)}
                className="slider-nav"
              >
                {items.images
                  ? items.images.map((vari, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <img
                          src={`${vari.images}`}
                          key={index}
                          alt=""
                          className="img-fluid"
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))
                  : items.images.map((vari, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <img
                          src={`${vari}`}
                          key={index}
                          alt=""
                          className="img-fluid"
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))}
              </Slider>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SmallImages;
```

This is the main component for product details which contain all the product details.
**Rightsidebar Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "../common/index.scss";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// import custom Components
import Service from "./common/service";
import BrandBlock from "./common/brand-block";
import NewProduct from "../common/new-product";
import Breadcrumb from "../common/breadcrumb";
import DetailsWithPrice from "./common/product/details-price";
import DetailsTopTabs from "./common/details-top-tabs";
import { addToCart, addToCartUnsafe, addToWishlist } from "../../actions";
import ImageZoom from "./common/product/image-zoom";
import SmallImages from "./common/product/small-image";

class RightSideBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      nav1: null,
      nav2: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      nav1: this.slider1,
      nav2: this.slider2,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      symbol,
      items,
      addToCart,
      addToCartUnsafe,
      addToWishlist,
    } = this.props;
    console.log(items);
    var products = {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      fade: true,
    };
    var productsnav = {
      slidesToShow: 3,
      swipeToSlide: true,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Breadcrumb title={" Product / " + items.name} />

        {/*Section Start*/}
        {items ? (
          <section className="section-b-space">
            <div className="collection-wrapper">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xl-12">
                          <div className="filter-main-btn mb-2">
                            <span className="filter-btn">
                              <i
                                className="fa fa-filter"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                              ></i>{" "}
                              filter
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-6 product-thumbnail">
                          <Slider
                            {...products}
                            asNavFor={this.state.nav2}
                            ref={(slider) => (this.slider1 = slider)}
                            className="product-slick"
                          >
                            {items.images.map((vari, index) => (
                              <div key={index}>
                                <ImageZoom
                                  images={vari.image_file}
                                  className="img-fluid image_zoom_cls-0"
                                />
                              </div>
                            ))}
                          </Slider>
                          {/* <SmallImages
                            items={items}
                            settings={productsnav}
                            navOne={this.state.nav1}
                          /> */}
                        </div>
                        <DetailsWithPrice
                          symbol={symbol}
                          items={items}
                          navOne={this.state.nav1}
                          addToCartClicked={addToCart}
                          BuynowClicked={addToCartUnsafe}
                          addToWishlistClicked={addToWishlist}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <DetailsTopTabs items={items} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-3 collection-filter">
                    {/* <BrandBlock/> */}
                    <Service />
                    {/*side-bar single product slider start*/}
                    <NewProduct />
                    {/*side-bar single product slider end*/}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {/*Section End*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let productId = ownProps.match.params.id;
  return {
    items: state.data.products.find((el) => el.id == productId),
    symbol: state.data.symbol,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  addToCart,
  addToCartUnsafe,
  addToWishlist,
})(RightSideBar);
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem you are having , are you getting an error. It is easier to tell us than for us to look at a large amount of code. Thanks

Comment: ímage is not displaying on the web